# How to overwrite Strapi plugin in Beta version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, strapi

In the Alpha version, we can edit users-permissions directly inside `the plugins folder`

[image: I can custom such as register API, login API over here]

It seems in **Beta version**, it will be installed by using `package.json` and the folder will be inside `node_module`.

so how can I do if I want to custom these files like using my new field instead `email`

Comment: You can check my code: https://github.com/victorray84/Strapi-Custom-Registration . I’ve created custom registration with image uploading. I’ve used MySQL. Please change the password from config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html#plugin-extensions) for the latest beta.

Basically is creating files with the same structure as the plugin.

For user-permissions plugin to overwrite the "register" method, you need to create /extensions/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js and then.

```
module.exports = {
  async register(ctx) {
    // Any code you want
   }
};
```

And so on for other methods/plugins

Comment: by the way I also got error like this 
`Error: The model backoffice_roles can't be found.` how can I deal with it

Comment: That doesn't look like a Strapi error, check the model definition, or try to create a new project, create a model and compare the differences, a lot of things changed from alpha to beta.